# JQuery - mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a quite simple code below. When I hover one of small red squares, another large color square appears.

Problem: When I move the cursor away this large square, this square will be hidden by `mouseleave().hide()`, but it doesn't work.

Please help.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c48b2k5L/)

HTML

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="black"></div>
      <div ID="black"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="green"></div>
      <div ID="green"></div>
    </td>
        <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="blue"></div>
      <div ID="blue"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="yellow"></div>
      <div ID="yellow"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.hot-spot').hover(function (e) {
    var square = $(this).data('target');
    $('#' + square).show();
    $('#' + square).mouseleave.hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: missing `()` ? ..

Comment: Tha is not how mouseleave works.... did you read the documentation? https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add brackets after mouseleave to show it's a function:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hot-spot').hover(function(e) {
    var square = $(this).data('target');
    $('#' + square).show();
    $('#' + square).mouseleave(function() {
      $('#' + square).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="black">a</div>
      <div ID="black">black</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="green">b</div>
      <div ID="green">green</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="blue">c</div>
      <div ID="blue">blue</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="hot-spot" data-target="yellow">d</div>
      <div ID="yellow">yellow</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mouseleave` takes a function [as an argument](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/#mouseleave-handler):

```
$(function() {
    $('.hot-spot').hover(function (e) {
    var square = $(this).data('target');
    $('#' + square).show();
    $('#' + square).mouseleave(function() { $('#' + square).hide() });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, MichaelvE and Cody very much for your help.  It works well.  Please let me know how to vote for both?  Thanks!